# Swift: How to localize a timer label

Tags: ios, swift, localization, countdowntimer

I created a 4:00 minute countdown timer (NStimer). At the end of the countdown the figures change to letters, so instead of showing 0:00, it'll show DONE. I know how to localize buttons, but how do I localize this string, which is only visible in the function below? The string does not appear in the Main.strings. I want to translate it into several languages.

```
func stopTimer() {

    if count == 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
        timerRunning = false
        playSound()
        timerLabel.text = "DONE"

           }
```

Comment: By using `NSLocalizedString`s http://www.appcoda.com/localization-tutorial-ios8/

Comment: thanks for the tutorial - will try to figure it out!

Comment: That tutorial makes it sound way too complicated. Start out by simply calling the NSLocalizedString function on every string you want to localize at some future time. The rest can be done later.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You don't  know how to use a different variable name?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I created this inside a function of my view controller:

```
timerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("DONE",comment:"end of countdown")
```

and then I added this to my localizable.strings of the source language

```
DONE="DONE";
```

and this in the localizable.strings of my target language

```
DONE="ENDE";
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://rshankar.com/internationalization-and-localization-of-apps-in-xcode-6-and-swift/), which I found more comprehensable.